# How to safely shutdown bitcoind ?

Tags: bitcoind

Surprised this one hasn't been asked yet.

But how / what is the recommended best practice for shutting down bitcoind ?

Right now I'm manually killing the process with either `sudo kill {pid}` or if this is failing (like just now) using `sudo pkill -9 -f bitcoind`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**EDIT: This answer is deprecated, it applied to an old version of the `bitcoind` client. Apparently RPC functionality is now removed. Please look at the other answers instead.**

I guess using `bitcoind stop`. I recommend this approach as killing the process could end you up with a corrupted database, from what I have experienced. Use `bitcoind --help` for all options and `bitcoind help` for all JSON-RPC commands.

Comment: Good thinking. Missed that.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore: `Error: Command line contains unexpected token 'stop', see bitcoind -h for a list of options.`. The correct way to stop `bitcoind` is `bitcoin-cli-stop` command (see the other answer with higher vote count).

Comment: The correct way, as shown by Aliakbar Ahmadi and confirmed by Jonathan Cross is `bitcoin-cli stop`. Note the last space as opposed to a hyphen.

Answer (score 76):

I'm not sure if `bitcoind stop` still works as RPC with newer releases, since somewhere in help sections it says RPC funcionality removed from bitcoind.

Try `bitcoin-cli stop`.

Comment: Confirmed `bitcoin-cli stop` works in version 11.

Comment: Still works in 2017! Use this.

Comment: does not work...  I did ./xxxcoin-cli stop   but nothing happen after that and ./xxxcoind also does not stopped.

Comment: Yes, it still works.

Comment: Does not work with my setup. I think first of all to be able to use `bitcoin-cli` you have to start `bitcoind` with option `server=1`. I did this and still `bitcoin-cli getinfo` is returning an error. So I suspect `bitcoin-cli` does not work properly. I have a process in `top` that is called `bitcoin-init`. I am not sure if this is the right process that should be active after I started `bitcoind` or if this some sort of initialisation process and since it uses 100% of my Raspberry CPU it might as well hang and this might be the root of the problem. I appreciate any input.

Comment: Try `sudo bitcoin-cli stop` if that throws an error about RPC credentials

Answer (score 9):

if you started it using 'bitcoind -daemon'
and you are using version 10 or above, then use 'bitcoin-cli stop'

Comment: Does not work for me. What could be the reason? Does the daemon need to be started as a server? Is `bitcoin-init` an initialisation process to `bitcoind`? Because that is my process in `top`.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, It works that `./bitcoin-cli -regtest stop`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you specify the same options that you normally use when running bitcoin, for example, if you use a different datadir:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\daemon
bitcoin-cli -datadir=C:\Bitcoin stop
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

bitcoin-cli -rpcuser=[username] -rpcpassword=[password] -rpcconnect=[ip] stop

Answer (score 0):

If using testnet, try `./bitcoin-cli -testnet stop`

Comment: `./bitcoin-cli stop` is enough

Comment: I don't know why this correct and the only working answer when on testnet was down-voted. `./bitcoin-cli stop` is definitely not enough when running 0.18rc on testnet.

Comment: It's only enough if you specifically added testnet=1 to your bitcoin.conf. Otherwise  the default is for mainnet!