# Bitcoin core V22 Authorization failed: Incorrect rpcuser or rpcpassword

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli

I have my full node connected through Tor. I ended up changing my onion service and now I'm getting `error: Could not locate RPC credentials. No authentication cookie could be found, and RPC password is not set.  See -rpcpassword and -stdinrpcpass.  Configuration file: (/home/ubuntu/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf)`

So I open up my bitcoin.conf, there was no rpc password or user name set to begin with and added one in so my .conf looks like the following.

```
prune=15000
proxy=127.0.0.1:9050
listen=1
bind=127.0.0.1
externalip=BLANK.onion
rpcuser=me
rpcpassword=mypassword
```

Which results in the following:

```
./bitcoin-cli listdescriptors 
error: Authorization failed: Incorrect rpcuser or rpcpassword
```

I also tried passing the -rpcuser and -rpcpassword directly without any luck.

I basically want to backup my wallets descriptors to Sparrow wallet since Electrum currently does not accept descriptors yet.

Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: Did you restart Bitcoin Core after modifying the bitcoin.conf file?

Comment: results in either error: Could not locate RPC credentials. No authentication cookie could be found, and RPC password is not set.  See -rpcpassword and -stdinrpcpass.  Configuration file: (/home/ubuntu/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf)

or 

error: Authorization failed: Incorrect rpcuser or rpcpassword 

upon adding or removing rpcuser and rpcpassword

Comment: You need to restart `bitcoind`; not just `bitcoin-cli`.

Comment: ./bitcoind stop
Error: Command line contains unexpected token 'stop', see bitcoind -h for a list of options.



https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/13696/how-to-safely-shutdown-bitcoind

Comment: Just use `killall bitcoind` to stop it. You can't use bitcoin-cli to send the stop command, as that needs bitcoin-cli, which doesn't work.